# how to connect a program in Prolog to a program in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, ffi, swi-prolog

I am new to Prolog and Java,at this point I am using JPL, SWI-Prolog and Eclipse. I was able to write and consult my Prolog program from Eclipse(Java) but how do I write a program in Prolog that will consult a Java program? What will be the elements of the Prolog program such that it can consult my simple java calculator program?

Comment: PLEASE SOMEBODY HELP!!!

Comment: Say I have this parent.pl code
parent(john, ann).
parent(john, mike).
parent(mary, mike).   
parent(mike, pat).
parent(mike, bob).
parent(pat, ben). 
parent(X, Y):- parent(X,Z),parent(Z,Y).

And in java I have coded that X can be a parent of Y only when X is 20years older than Y. In this way I can be sure of the X I am working with if there are more than one X's. I know prolog alone can do this but JUST LEARNING HERE...

Answer (score 0):

Use JPL from within Prolog:

http://www.swi-prolog.org/packages/jpl/prolog_api/overview.html#calling_methods_of_Java_objects_...

Answer (score 0):

To install Prolog on eclipse you need a plugin called Prolog Development Tools (ProDT).

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/prolog - plugin can be found here.

To download the eclipse Marketplace... 
But to install this plugin you will need to download the eclipse market place client.
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/prolog-development-tools-prodt

If dragging the install doesn't work for you, it didn't for me either, so right click and copy link address.
Then in eclipse Window -> preferences -> Install/Update and find the subfolder on the left hand side within it called Avaialable Software Sites -> add -> put in a name like Marketplace and copy the address below. - > OK -> Apply and close.

Help -> Install New Software -> select MarketPlace from the drop down (or whatever you called it) and then finish.

(Or if that doesn't work try Help -> Install New Software -> Add and put in the same address and hope for the best)

**If you already have the market place client then go to Help->Eclipse Marketplace -> and use the search bar to find and then download "prolog"**